# Source and destination must not be the same [ERROR]

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

When I try to do a Cordova build for android --prod --release. I get this error:

> Source and destination must not be the same.
>
> Error: Source and destination must not be the same.
>
> at checkPaths (C:\Users\est-acoelho\Documents\app-movel-master\app-movel-master\node_modules\cordova-common\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\copy-sync\copy-sync.js:185:11)
>
> at Object.copySync (C:\Users\est-acoelho\Documents\app-movel-master\app-movel-master\node_modules\cordova-common\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\copy-sync\copy-sync.js:25:20)
>
> at updatePathWithStats (C:\Users\est-acoelho\Documents\app-movel-master\app-movel-master\node_modules\cordova-common\src\FileUpdater.js:103:24)
>
> at C:\Users\est-acoelho\Documents\app-movel-master\app-movel-
>   master\node_modules\cordova-common\src\FileUpdater.js:298:19
>
> at Array.forEach ()
>
> at Object.mergeAndUpdateDir (C:\Users\est-acoelho\Documents\app-movel-master\app-movel-master\node_modules\cordova-common\src\FileUpdater.js:296:33)
>   at updateWww (C:\Users\est-acoelho\Documents\app-movel-master\app-movel-master\platforms\android\cordova\lib\prepare.js:157:17)
>
> at Api.module.exports.prepare (C:\Users\est-acoelho\Documents\app-movel-master\app-movel-master\platforms\android\cordova\lib\prepare.js:56:19)
>
> at Api.prepare (C:\Users\est-acoelho\Documents\app-movel-master\app-movel-master\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:177:45)
>
> at C:\Users\est-acoelho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\prepare.js:105:36

I have already done a Cordova platform remove android and a Cordova platform add android.

I see this issue occurs on Android 8.0.0 but I have to use this one, because Google Play Console only let me upload an app with API +26 (+8)

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Can anyone solve this?

Comment: I managed to solve it. Just used another similar project, and copied the files into it. But i think that the error occurs with the platforms. Try to remove and add android again. If that doesn´t work , try to cordova build another project with android 8.0.0!